# how can i read data from socket continuously using aynctask

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio

I am new to android, and I am trying to read data from the socket using async task. But after reading data once from the socket, AsyncTask gets terminated. Is there any way to execute AsyncTask continuously??

Currently, from below code, I am able to display data on screen just once. But I need to display data continuously as soon as new data comes in the socket.

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";
        TextView textResponse;
        int value;

        Client(String addr, int port, TextView textResponse) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        this.textResponse = textResponse;
        }

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
        1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                byte ch = '1';
                Character c;
                DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                // dout.writeUTF(ch);
                dout.write(ch);
                dout.flush();
        int bytesRead;
                InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
                byte buf[] = new byte[1000];


                        input = socket.getInputStream();
                        in = new DataInputStream(input);
                        System.out.print(in.readInt());
                        value= in.readInt();
                        System.out.print(value);
                        dout.write(ch);
                        dout.flush();
//                in.read(buf);
//                for(byte b:buf)
//                {
//                    c = (char)b;
//                    System.out.print(c);
//
//            }}


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("UnknownHostException: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("IOException: " + e.toString());
//        } finally {
//        if (socket != null) {
//        try {
//        socket.close();
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//        e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        }
        }
        return value;
        }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("Exception","result"+result);
        textResponse.setText("" +result);


        }

        }
```

I used a handler to call sync task but it didn't work. Below shows the code for the handler.

```
myClient = new Client(hostname, port,tvCount);
         Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myClient.execute();
                //Do something after 100ms
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: call the async task often using thread and handler.

Comment: myClient = new Client(hostname, port,tvCount);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
//            public void run() {
                myClient.execute();
                //Do something after 100ms
            }
      }, 5000);

Comment: @JyotiJK, i tried calling with handler but it didn't work.

Comment: why it doesn't work?

Comment: `"But I need to display data continuously as soon as new data comes in the socket."` so make a loop inside `doInBackground` method

Comment: Loop doesn't help, as it needs to go to doPostExecute method for displaying output. So untill the loop end it stays in doInBackground only.

Comment: yes it helps, read `AsyncTask` documentation carefully, in particular `"The 4 steps"` section

Comment: Can you please share some example @pskink

Comment: so did you read `"The 4 steps"` section? step #2 ?

Comment: yes its about doInBackround

Comment: have you read it to the end? read this section **carefully**

Comment: Try creating a service and after connecting to server put it in an endless while loop

Comment: i hope you already know how to implement your loop in `doInBackround` method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        new Client(hostname, port,tvCount).execute(); 
        //do something
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

Comment: Thanks it displays data but after 2 minutes and that is to long to wait. Is there any way to display data after some seconds.

Comment: my asynctask is in different class and i am calling it from different class. Does that make this delay ?

Comment: `but after 2 minutes and that is to long to wait` . I didn't get you can u explain a bit. Here I have given 5000 ms as example. You can change it as you want

Comment: I think your task took that much time to execute.

Comment: The time it took, is it because of creating socket again ?

Comment: did you check the time of onpostexecute log display everytime?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    public static Socket clientSocket;
             public class socketconnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                Context mcontext;
                String SERVER_IP;
                int SocketServerPORT;
                String connectionmessage;

                public socketconnection(String message, String ipaddress, String port, Socket client,Context m_context) {
                    connectionmessage = message;
                    SERVER_IP = ipaddress;
                    SocketServerPORT = Integer.parseInt(port);
                    clientSocket = client;
                    mcontext = m_context;
                }


                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... String) {
                    String response = null;
                    try{
                        clientSocket = new Socket();
                        clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SocketServerPORT),10000);
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        mBufferOut.write(connectionmessage);
                        mBufferOut.flush();
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while (true) {
                            socketstatus = false;
                            int ch = in.read();
                            if ((ch < 0) || (ch == '`')) {
                                String serverResponse = buffer.toString();
                                Log.d("serverResponse"," " +serverResponse);
                                if (serverResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("") || serverResponse == null || serverResponse.isEmpty()){    
                              //do your stuff
                                    break;
                                }else {
                                    // do your stuff with the response you recieve
                                    buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());

                                }
                            } else {
                                buffer.append((char) ch);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch(SocketTimeoutException s) {
                        Log.d("Socket_timed_out","" +s);
                    }  catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        Log.d("UnknownHostException","" +e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        Log.d("IOException","" +e);
                    }catch (NullPointerException e){
                        Log.d("NullPointerException","" +e);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
    }
```

Try this inside your Service class So as it will run continuously once it is started from your app launcher activity or some base activity you wish. This is a working solution for receiving messages from server Socket. 
[Services in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)